# Connecting Function Generator to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, signal-processing

I want to send a function generator's signal to an Arduino UNO Analog pin. Can I use an Oscilloscope probe connected to the function generator output BNC, set to 1x to connect to the Arduino headers using jumper wires? I did read through the manuals of the function generator, but couldn't find a solution.

The function generator available is Tenma 72-14110.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can connect the function generator to an analog pin of the Arduino. The probe and the jumper wires are just wires here, nothing special. You should also connect the function generators ground to the Arduinos ground (!).

But: Be sure to stay in the Arduinos voltage range (0 to 5V) with the function generators signal. If you apply a higher or negative voltage, you can destroy the Arduino. As long, as you stay inside that range, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Thanks, I read that the probes are used for 'probe compensation' in oscilloscopes and that they have resistors in them - hence was not sure if I could use them.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to chrisl's answer, I would recommend putting a
10 kΩ series resistor in series between the function generator and
the Arduino.

This is just for safety: if the function generator accidentally goes out
of the  Arduino's safe voltage range, the resistor will limit the
current that flows through the input pin's protection diodes. These
diodes are rated to only 1 mA, and a 10 kΩ resistor should
greatly expand the range of voltages you can send without frying them.